# Ways to distribute $21$ different books among $3$ persons

Tags: combinatorics

We have $21$ different books and we have to distribute them to $3$ persons: $A$, $B$ and $C$. $A$ and $B$ together must have twice the number of books that $C$ has. What is the sum of the total ways to do it?

So:
\begin{align*}
A+B &= 2C,\\
A+B+C &= 21,\\
2C+C &= 21,\\
C &= 7,\\ 
A+B& = 14.
\end{align*}

I have been thinking the answer must be:

$$S = 2\cdot(\frac{21!}{1!\cdot13!\cdot7!} + \frac{21!}{2!\cdot12!\cdot7!} + \dots + \frac{21!}{7!\cdot7!\cdot7!}),$$

because $A$ can have $1$ book and $B$ can have $13$ books, $A$ can have $2$ books and $B$ can have $12$ books, ..., $A$ can have $7$ books and $B$ can have $7$ books.

Then I multiply with $2$ because $A$ can have $13$ books and $B$ can have $1$ book, etc. So by multiplying with $2$ I make sure that I have all the distributions because $A$ and $B$ are different persons.

Is this solution correct? Any more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $21$ different books. $C$ gets $7$ books and rest $14$ books are divided between $A$ and $B$.

First, number of ways to choose $7$ books for $C = {21 \choose 7}$

Then, for each of the rest $14$ books, there are two choices - it either goes to $A$ or to $B$. So number of ways to distribute books to $A$ and $B$ is $ \ 2^{14}$. This includes cases where either $A$ or $B$ does not receive any book and all $14$ books go to the other.

So total number of ways $ = \displaystyle \small  {21 \choose 7} \cdot 2^{14}$

Comment: We can also consider 2^14 as the number of elements of the power set for a set that has as elements the 14 remains books. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Also the question does not state that $A$ and $B$ both must have at least one book each. So we include cases where one of them has no books. But if we had to only count arrangements where they both had at least one book, it would be $(2^{14} - 2)$ instead of $2^{14}$.